# Render an array in React JS using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, axios, render

I have this code that fetches categories from a remote using `Axios` and I want to list the names of these categories in a pop up window after clicking on a button:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";


  class CategoryView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        catN: [],
     };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getCategories(this.state.categoryData.catN);
  }
 
// fetch all categories
  getCategories() {
    axios
        .get("/v1/categories")
        .then((res) => {
          var cats = [],
              catsN = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < res.data.items.length; i++) {
            cats[i] = res.data.items[i];
            catsN[i] = cats[i].name;
          }
          console.log(res);
          this.setState({
            catN: catsN,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log("Get Error"));
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <div>
                <Popup trigger= {<Button variant="outline-primary">Add to Category</Button>}
                       modal
                       closeOnDocumentClick
                >
                  <ul className="categorylist">
                  </ul>
                  <Button variant="primary" size="lg" block>
                    Show Categories
                  </Button>
                </Popup>
              </div>
              <p
                style={{
                  float: "left",
                  marginLeft: "30px",
                  marginRight: "20px",
                }}
              >
              </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default VideoView;
```

My problem is that I don't know how to list the categories names in the render method, the `console` shows somthing like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyKAN.jpg) for the `get()` request.

How can I render the list of names of categories?

Comment: I see you are making rest call on componentLoad.. You need to change that to the button click . and set the data in the state variable.

Comment: Can you give me an idea on how to set the data in the state variable? I thought that was already done in the `axios.get()` method

Comment: Yeah my bad I missed that. It is fine, just you need to make rest call on Button click

Answer (score 0):

Since catN is an array use can use `map()` method to display the names

```js
        {catN.length ? (
          <ul>
            {catN.map((ele) => (
              <li>{ele}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        ) : null}
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but I always receive the error `catsN is not defined`

Comment: You this.state.catsN instead of catsN .

Comment: I have tried this, unfortunately the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example for rendering a array of todos in react:

```
class Todos extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state={
todos:[{label:wake up ,completed:true}, {label : got to work, completed :false}]
}

return ( <div id="todo">
<ul>{this.state.todos.map(item=>(
<li>{item.label} {item.completed?"completed":"incomplete"}</li>
 )</ul>
</div>)
}
```